# Counting "Yes" in multiple columns in a data-frame using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Suppose I am having the following data. [As requested I am adding the data]

```
col1 <- c("Team A", "Team A", "Team A", "Team B", "Team B", "Team B", "Team C", "Team C", "Team C", "Team D", "Team D", "Team D")
col2 <- c("High",   "Medium", "Medium", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "Medium", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium")
col3 <- c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes")
col4 <- c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes")
df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

```
# Col1      Col2    Col3    Col4
# Team A    High    Yes     No
# Team A    Medium  Yes     Yes
# Team A    Medium  No      No
# Team B    Low     No      Yes
# Team B    Low     No      Yes
# Team B    Low     Yes     No
# Team C    High    No      No
# Team C    Medium  Yes    Yes
# Team C    Low     No     No 
# Team D    Medium  Yes    Yes
# Team D    Medium  Yes    No
# Team D    Medium  Yes    Yes
```

I want to use `dplyr` function to get the following result. Status_1 would need to be the count of the number of "Yes" in Col3 against each team while Status_2 would be the count of "Yes" in Col4 against each team

```
       High Medium  Low Status_1    Status_2
Team A    1      2    0        2           1
Team B    0      0    3        1           2
Team C    1      1    1        1           1
Team D    0      3    0        3           2
```

I am able to generate the normal summary but for the last two columns of "Status_1" and "Status_2" using the following statement. Can anyone help, please?

```
df %>%
  group_by(Col1, Col2) %>%
  summarise(Count = n()) %>%
  spread(Col1, Count, fill = 0)
```

Comment: it is easier to help if you provide some sample data, e.g. with `dput()`

Comment: As request data has been entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, group the data by `col1` to count the number of `Yes` in `col3` and `col4`. Then group again by all columns and count the number of observations in each group using `n()`. Finally, use `tidyr::pivot_wider` to transform data from long to wide.

```
df %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(col3:col4), ~ sum(. == "Yes")) %>%
  rename(status_1 = col3, status_2 = col4) %>% 
  group_by_all %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = col2, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))

# # A tibble: 4 x 6
#   col1   status_1 status_2  High Medium   Low
#   <fct>     <int>    <int> <int>  <int> <int>
# 1 Team A        2        1     1      2     0
# 2 Team B        1        2     0      0     3
# 3 Team C        1        1     1      1     1
# 4 Team D        3        2     0      3     0
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use use `grepl` and `sum` to simply count the matches:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% # your example data was sotred as factor
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  summarise(High = sum(grepl("High", col2)),
            Medium = sum(grepl("Medium", col2)),
            Low = sum(grepl("Low", col2)),
            Status_1 = sum(grepl("Yes", col3)),
            Status_2 = sum(grepl("Yes", col4)))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   col1    High Medium   Low Status_1 Status_2
#>   <chr>  <int>  <int> <int>    <int>    <int>
#> 1 Team A     1      2     0        2        1
#> 2 Team B     0      0     3        1        2
#> 3 Team C     1      1     1        1        1
#> 4 Team D     0      3     0        3        2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Instead of `grepl` you can also use `str_count` or `str_detect` from `stringr`. All are doing the same in this case. The important thing is to use `sum` so counts are aggreagted to one value.